# XNA 4.0: Blender .fbx File Won't Display 3D Model

Tags: xna, c#, blender, 3d-meshes

So I followed the basic 3D model display tutorial found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197293%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx

And while I know this is for XNA 3.1, I can still get the screen to show and the background color to change fine.  The model file seems to be accepted in the method below:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        grudmud = Content.Load<Model>("Models\\Vikings_grudmud");

        aspectRatio = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio;
    }
```

The model was created in Blender, so perhaps I'm missing a step in creating a mesh or certain texture for it?  I have colored it in Blender and it's a simple blocky humanoid figure.  Is there a scaling I should check in Blender so the camera in XNA is not inside the object?

Here's where I actually draw the object and set out some basic properties:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Aqua);

        Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[grudmud.Bones.Count];
        grudmud.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in grudmud.Meshes) {

            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects) {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationY(modelRotation)
                   * Matrix.CreateTranslation(modelPosition);
                effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, 
                    Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
                effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f),
                    aspectRatio, 1.0f, 10000.0f);
                effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

The initial camera and player model positions:

```
Vector3 modelPosition = Vector3.Zero;
    float modelRotation = 0.0f;
    Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 50.0f, 5000.0f);
```

[image: Under Content project thingy.]

I haven't even attempted to implement the face texture yet.

[image: My model in blender, camera and all.]

It seems to have a wireframe/mesh, I've just colored in the faces.  The model is pretty much centered around the origin.

Am I exporting it wrong?  Do I need to specify lighting/camera angles any further?

Comment: what is the position of the camera and the what is the position of the model?

Comment: Looks like the camera is 0, 50, and 5,000 for x,y,z respectively.  The Vector3.Zero sets all components to 0 so in theory 0,0,0.

Comment: Ok, This Must Be A Problem With Loading Your Model Or Just The Model Itself.

Comment: Uhh does anyone know how to unwrap the entire texture/materials of the model so I only need one .tga file?  I have one image and the rest of the faces are colored in with "material" according to Blender.

Comment: Ok, so after editing the sample's .tga texture file to completely black, the model still rendered.  Im seriously thinking I am forgetting to add something in blender before exporting as a .fbx but can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Autodesk_FBX Seems to be helping with the specs of Blender -> XNA. After trying other sample .fbx models, a .tga is not even needed. Blender must be messing up the .fbx file somehow.

Comment: Try playing with the export scale. Depending on your camera, it might be too small to be seen.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem when following the same tutorial. I took Fibericon's advice and played with the export scale. I had to increase it to 100.0 (from 1.0) for the model to display properly when compiled in XNA. As an alternative, I found decreasing the distance of the camera from 5000.0f to 50.0f made the model visible.

This begs the question *why*. The suggested export scale based on [this help page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Autodesk_FBX) is 1.0. The scale of my model's objects are all 1.0. My XNA code is identical to the OP's.

Regardless, it's working. Thanks Fibericon!